# when fetch images from firebase, tableView not scroll to row Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, scrolltop

I begin to create a chat app and want it to scroll to bottom every time I enter text or image. For text, the code is perfect to execute scrollToRow after tableView reload. However, **the image always shows under the keyboard**, I tried many ways to solve this issue but still get the same result.
[image does not show above the keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSue1.png)
[image is under keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKVqg.png)

```
class ChatTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

private let reuseIdentifier = "reuseIdentifier"
private let chatImageIdentifier = "chatImageCell"

var sSection = 0
var rRow = 0

var commentRef: DatabaseReference!
var firebaseHandle: DatabaseHandle?
var dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot?
let uid = FirebaseHelper.shared.getUserId()
let username = FirebaseHelper.shared.getUsername()
let email = FirebaseHelper.shared.getUserEmail()

var comments = [Comment]()

var intArray: [Int]? {
    didSet{
        guard let intArray = intArray else {return}

        self.sSection = intArray[0]
        self.rRow = intArray[1]

        commentRef = FirebaseHelper.shared.getCommentRef(firebaseRef: .comments, section: sSection, row: rRow)

        comments = []
        tableView.reloadData()

        observeCommentsFromFirebase {

        }

        setUpKeyboardObserver()

    }
}


func observeCommentsFromFirebase(completion: @escaping (()->Void)) {

    firebaseHandle = commentRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "timeStamp").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        self.dataSnapshot = snapshot

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any]{
            let comment = Comment(dictionary: dictionary)

            self.comments.append(comment)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()


                self.handleKeyboardDidShow()
                completion()
            }

        }

    }, withCancel: nil)

}

func setUpKeyboardObserver() {

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardDidShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)

}

@objc func handleKeyboardDidShow() {
    if comments.count > 0 {

        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: comments.count - 1, section: 0)
        self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: false)
    }
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.register(ChatTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    tableView.register(ChatImageCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: chatImageIdentifier)
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    tableView.allowsSelection = false
    tableView.backgroundColor = grayColor

    tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive

    view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap)))

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleDismiss))

    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

    tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
}

@objc func handleDismiss() {

            if let firebaseHandle = firebaseHandle {
                self.commentRef.removeObserver(withHandle: firebaseHandle)
            }

    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let comment = comments[indexPath.row]

    if comment.imageUrl != "" {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: chatImageIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ChatImageCell
        if comments.count != 0 {
            cell.comment = comment
        }

        return cell

    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ChatTableViewCell

        if comments.count != 0 {
            cell.comment = comment
        }

        return cell
    }
}

@objc func uploadImage() {

    showImageActionSheet()

}

extension ChatTableViewController: UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

func showImageActionSheet() {

    // declaring action sheet
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    // declaring camera button
    let camera = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default) { (action) in

        // if there is camera, then execute
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
            self.showPicker(with: .camera)
        }

    }

    // declaring library button
    let library = UIAlertAction(title: "Library", style: .default) { (action) in

        // if there is library, then execute
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary) {
            self.showPicker(with: .photoLibrary)
        }
    }

    // declaring cancel button
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel)


    // add action to the sheet
    alertController.addAction(camera)
    alertController.addAction(library)
    alertController.addAction(cancel)

    // present action sheet to the user
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func showPicker(with source: UIImagePickerController.SourceType) {

    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.allowsEditing = true
    picker.sourceType = source
    self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

// fetch selected image from info with key

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    var selectedImage: UIImage?
    // declaring editedImage
    if let editedImage = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage {
        selectedImage = editedImage
    } else if let originalImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        selectedImage = originalImage
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

      FirebaseHelper.shared.uploadImage(image: selectedImage, firebaseRef: .comment_images, viewController: self) {
                    urlString in

                    let timeStamp = Helper.shared.dateOfCurrentTimeZone()

                    let childKey = FirebaseHelper.shared.getChildKey()

                    let profileImageUrlString: String

                    if let profileImageUrl = FirebaseHelper.shared.getPhotUrl() {

                        profileImageUrlString = profileImageUrl.absoluteString

                    } else {
                        profileImageUrlString = ""
                    }

                    let values: [String: Any] = ["text": "", "uid": self.uid, "timeStamp": timeStamp, "childkey": childKey, "username": self.username, "email": self.email ?? "", "imageUrl": urlString, "profileImageUrl": profileImageUrlString]
        self.commentRef.child(childKey).updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (error, dataRef) in
            if error != nil {
                Helper.shared.alertController(title: "Error", message: error!.localizedDescription, viewController: self)
                return
            }


        })

    }
}
```

}

Comment: I spent a lot of time trying to make this work, when I "discovered" a really [interesting trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43480887/load-tableview-from-bottom-scroll-up-reverse-tableview-ios). Basically, you "flip" the table up-side-down, so inserting new rows at position 0 will make it appear as if they are been inserted at the bottom - talk about saving a tone of time and solving a whole bunch of edge case.  You might need to look around for other examples, but that's the basic idea ;) (I did a quick google for "swift uitableview scroll to bottom flip y")

Comment: @MadProgrammer, the problem is only for images not texts, I have tried this method, it is not worked for uploading image

Comment: *"the image always shows under the keyboard"* - Then display the view by the size of the keyboard - pretty common task (I might be misunderstanding)