# How to make List reversed in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm new in SwiftUI, trying to make something like `reverse` in Android `LinearLayoutManager`

```java
messagesRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.messagesRecyclerView);

manager = new LinearLayoutManager(activity, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, true); // => true means reverse layout
messagesRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
```

in this case everything goes from bottom to top.

Everything useful what I can find is `tableview` reverse:
[Load tableview from bottom, scroll up (reverse tableview) (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43480887/load-tableview-from-bottom-scroll-up-reverse-tableview-ios)

```
//In ViewDidLoad
conversationTableView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -(CGFloat)(Double.pi));

//In cellForRowAtIndexPath
cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi));
```

but I don't know how to add it into `List` (seems like it just a wrapper around TableView). 
Another approach here: [How to populate UITableView from the bottom upwards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28105905/how-to-populate-uitableview-from-the-bottom-upwards)

```swift
                List {
                    ForEach(itemsData.messages) { item in
                        ChatRow(item: item)
                    }
                    Text("Load more messages...")
                        .onAppear() {
                            print("Load more messages...")
                            self.itemsData.next()
                    }
                }
```

My assumption is to get something `.onAppear` or `override` methods to make this work.

Seems like SwiftUI too young to go that deep.

Another question: **do they have an API to programmatically scroll in List**?

Hope I'm not duplicating any questions.

Using it for anonymous chat app https://en.lonje.com/

Comment: What about `itemsData.messages.reversed()` ?

Comment: @Jorge this is where I started, but:
*  it not aligned
* always jumps to top on update
* always resets position on any `messages` change

Comment: Found this great article, exactly what I've asked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57258846/how-to-make-a-swiftui-list-scroll-automatically

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a trick on `UITableView` that you flip the table and each cell. So it appears to be filling from bottom. You can do this trick in SwiftUI too:

Fully Working Demo:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var ids = [String]()

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            List(ids, id: \.self) { id in
                Text(id)
                    .scaleEffect(x: 1, y: -1, anchor: .center) //  Flip list items here
            }
            .scaleEffect(x: 1, y: -1, anchor: .center) //  Flip the list itself here
            
            Button("Touch") {
                self.ids.append(UUID().uuidString)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **Note that** I replaced all data with a mock duo lack of information about your structures.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I've looked for. But in my improved example `reversed List` have strange `padding`, it looks like some List "header" or something else, can't get rid of it. Here is my snippet: https://pastebin.com/rRGtewzG

Comment: You should not update your question using the answer. Please revert it back to the original and ask a new question about that wired padding and link it in the comment here. So I can investigate on it ;)

Comment: Updated, thank you for quick reply.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58516228/bottom-padding-in-reverted-list-swiftui

 Btw, may be you can recommend some example for programmatic scrolling in list, for instance how to `scrollToPosition(at: i)`?

Comment: There is no direct api yet, but I will look for a workaround

Comment: About direct API may be exists method to focus list on some item or at list set some offset?

Comment: What about Lists that have Edit enabled and implement the onDelete modifier?

Answer (score 1):

@cipais's answer worked well.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61036551/12208004

```
List(chatController.messages, id: \.self) { message in
    MessageView(message.text, message.isMe)
        .rotationEffect(.radians(.pi))
        .scaleEffect(x: -1, y: 1, anchor: .center)
}
.rotationEffect(.radians(.pi))
.scaleEffect(x: -1, y: 1, anchor: .center)
```